# Python matplotlib.pyplot Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to run the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# squares.py: page 324-326

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

squares = []
input_value = []

for x in range(-10, 11):
    input_value.append(x)
    n = x ** 2
    squares.append(n)

plt.plot(input_value, squares, linewidth=1)

plt.title("Square Numbers", fontsize=14)        # Set chart title
plt.xlabel("Value", fontsize=12)                # Set label x-axis
plt.ylabel("Square of Value", fontsize=12)      # Set label y-axis

plt.grid(True)                                  # Add grid to graph
plt.rc('grid', linestyle="-", color='black')

plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=14)      # Set size of tick labels

plt.show()
```

And I am getting the error in the attached picture

[image]

Comment: How have you installed `matplotlib`, and are you sure you installed it for python 3.x rather than python 2

Comment: Yes, I am very sure I installed it on Python 3.6.  How can I check?

Comment: You can try to upgrade `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` or reinstall it. Your code worked for me.

Comment: Something went wrong during matplotlib install. You may need to uninstall and then reinstall it. Further help can only be given if precise information about the system and the way matplotlib has been installed are given in the question.